# Is it possible to use two constructors in a single php class?

Tags: php, overloading

Is it possible to use two constructors in a single php class like:

```
class php{

   // first constructor
   function __construct(){

   }

   // second constructor             
   function __construct(){

   }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The answer is no: not possible, but probably there is a solution to your problem, so we need to know the problem.

Comment: Please dont ask silly question for which you will find documentation very easily.

Comment: To be fair, it's not such a silly question since many languages allow multiple constructors. You can't in PHP but you can use optional parameter to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @this.lau_ overloading would be the bomb!

Comment: Many languages are allowing overloading, but PHP not. I guess that the solution of this.lau_ is the solution for the OP, but we don't know the problem exact. Maybe he does want to archieve something else. Maybe he does want to something with inheritance and constructors (i don't think so, but you never know).

Comment: @this.lau Using conditional statement is not that difficult, so that one has to directly post it in stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1):

When I need to emulate overloading, I use special argument ordering an treatment.  For example, the following behaves like a function with 4 variants:

```
function read(&$bytes = null, $off = 0, $len = 0)
{
    // Simply checking for null is not useful for references,
    // A value created as a parameter will be null, but the number
    // of arguments will still exist, check the argument count instead
    // of the default values.
    if (0 === func_num_args()) {
        // Equals: read();
    }

    $off = (int) $off;
    $end = min($off + $len, $this->length) ? $this->length;
    // Equals: read($b, $i, $l);
}
```

The above emulates:

```
function read();

function read(&$bytes);

function read(&$bytes, $off);

function read(&$bytes, $off, $len);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two constructors, but you can use optional parameters to achieve the same thing. Something like this:

```
class Example {

    function __construct($param = null) {
        if ($param === null) {
           // First case
        } else {
           // Second case
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

It's not possible to define multiple constructors in one class..
Like below define

```
class Example {

   function __construct(){

   } // this is for the first construct

   function __construct(){

   } //this is for the second construct

}
```

So, how would you know which constructor is called first?